# Regular Expression to validate Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

In our application we need to check if a given string has **only numbers** and is of **length 8** .  How can we specify this conditions in a regular expression ?

Comment: You want exactly 8 digits or maximum 8 digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch("YourInput", @"^\d{8}$");
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it so difficult to write this regex? 3 persons have responded in 3 ways that are partially wrong. This clearly shows why regexes shouldn't ever be used! Because you can **think** you know how they work, and then they'll bite your `^a([a-z])\1$` (it's a joke for persons that know regexes :-) ).

The regex is `^[0-9]{8}$`. You **anchor** the regex with `^` and `$` at the beginning and the end of the string. You don't use fancy `\d`, because the .NET Regex considers it to match 09E6 ০ BENGALI DIGIT ZERO (non european digits) unless you activate its ECMA mode (`RegexOptions.ECMAScript`). Javascript with `\d` means only 0-9 digits. And if you really really want to use `\d`, remember to escape the `\` or put a verbatim string literal sign before the string (the `@"something"`)

Answer (score 1):

> ^[0-9]{8}$

Simple and clean. You set the acceptable value range, inside the ['s, and the number of hits inside the {'s.
^ and $ to specify start and end of string, to make sure you don't match sections of strings, containing 8 numbers, as Xanatos says.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to put a ^ and a $ at the beginning and the end. Depending on how it does the check, x1245678 would pass.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried [`FilteredTextBox Demonstration`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx) in Ajax Control Toolkit?

It's pretty cool.

[image]